# http://stackexchange.com/about does not contain any overview info

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow

Neither the home page, nor the about us page, contain any overview info about the site. For examples, why and when the site was created, and any major direction changes. There are many diferent wordings of the mission and intent on different pages such as the advertising page, legal, and privacy pages. Which is the current wording? Why?
Everything on the site is CC-BY-SA maybe 3.0. Why?
There are many different question boards. Sometimes it's obvious why the distiction. Others not so much. If there's a single page summing up those reasons, please point to it.

There a lot of overview info and good pointers to places to start that other companies put on either their home page, or if their homepage is a launcher like stackoverflow's is, then they collect that on their "about us" page. Instead, the stackoverflow about us page goes straight to the team photos, and isn't helpful in explaining anything.

Comment: You mean the [tour page](http://stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: you seem to be mixing up stackoverflow and stackexchange here...

Comment: Fair point, seems [about us](http://stackexchange.com/about) should show [tour](http://stackexchange.com/tour) as the site overview

Comment: @AndrewT. The problem is that us (=the company) is not us (=the communities, the QA system, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

We just rolled out a new About page for stackexchange.com that includes a brief history, timeline, and similar "history of the company" type information. Live on https://stackexchange.com/about/, partial screen shot below:

[image: se.com/about with timeline]

This page doesn't capture all of the reasons behind our philosophy because an average passer-by isn't interested in that level of detail. Philosophies and the evolution of the product and policies are a massive, complex topic, so the history of those remains on the blog, in podcasts, and on meta.